# SQL - select rows that their child rows's column contains specific string

Tags: sql

For example:

```
RouteID    StopName 
1           stop_1 
1           stop_2
1           stop_3 
2           stop_1 
2           stop_2 
3           stop_4 
4           stop_5
```

I want to select the route that it has a stop named 'stop_1', I expect the results as follows:

```
RouteID    StopName 
 1           stop_1 
 1           stop_2
 1           stop_3 
 2           stop_1 
 2           stop_2
```

**EDIT**

How about the `RouteID` is from the table `Route`
and `StopName` is from the table `Stop`? Actually, the above table is their relation table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an inner query that selects the routes for that:

```
select r.RouteID, s.StopName from route r
inner join stop s on r.StopID = s.StopID
where RouteID in
  (select t1.RouteID from route t1
  where exists (select * from stop s2 where t1.StopID = s2.StopID and s2.StopName = 'stop_1'))
order by r.RouteID, s.StopName
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9894f/7)

Comment: how about the RouteID is from the table Routes, and StopName is from the table Stop?

Comment: You can then create a join to StopName table.

Comment: can u give an example?

Answer (score 1):

**New Answer for your edit**

Again, assuming routes table is named `Routes` and your relation table is named `RouteStops`.

```
SELECT * FROM Routes r
JOIN RouteStops rs ON rs.RouteID = r.RouteID
WHERE rs.StopName = 'stop_1'
```

**Old Answer:**

For the sake of example, I'm going to assume your table name is Routes

```
SELECT * FROM Routes r
JOIN Routes r2 ON r.RouteID = r2.RouteID
WHERE r2.StopName = 'stop_1'
```

I'm basically joining the table with itself whenever a route contains `stop_1` and then listing all of that routes entries.

Answer (score 0):

**New Answer:**

Supposing that from the expected results you mean that you want to get the rows that shares the same `RouteID` with stop_1, I will do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME
WHERE RouteID IN 
(
SELECT

RouteID

FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME

WHERE StopName = 'stop_1'
)
```

---

**Old answer: IGNORE, KEPT JUST DUE TO COMMENTS**

In oracle syntax, you can use the Sub String function. it takes the first input the string you want to work with, second the starting position, the last one is the length, so  1----------- is 12 characters long, the statement will be the following

```
substr(your_column, 12, LENGTH(your_column) - 12)
```

now this logic can be utilized as following:

```
SELECT
Your desired values to get

FROM
(
SELECT

substr(your_column, 1, 1) AS ID, substr(your_column, 12, LENGTH(your_column) - 12) AS VALUE

FROM YOUR TABLE
)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure all those `-` are just a way of presenting a table with 2 columns.

Comment: @Szymon, that will be bad for me ! :D, wasted a good logic for a not clear question then

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT ROUTID 
FROM Routes R
JOIN Stop S ON R.RouteID = S.RouteID
WHERE S.StopName IN ('stop_1 ','stop_2','stop_3')
```